# Error Register asp MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to ask about an error in my program, I create a register and login page but I have problem about that.

This the my code in UserControler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RegisstrationAndLogin.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace RegisstrationAndLogin.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //registration action
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Registration Post Action
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Registration([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified, ActivationCode")]User user)
        {
            bool Status = false;
            string message = "";
            // model validation
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var isExist = IsEmailExist(user.EmailID);
                if(isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exist");
                    return View(user);
                }

                user.ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                user.Password = Crypto.Hash(user.Password);
                user.ConfirmPassword = Crypto.Hash(user.ConfirmPassword); //
                user.IsEmailVerified = false;

                using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    dc.Users.Add(user);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    //Send Email To User
                    SendVerificationLinkEmail(user.EmailID,user.ActivationCode.ToString());
                    message = "Registration SuccessFully Done. Account activation link " + " has been sent to your email id: " + user.EmailID;
                    Status = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            ViewBag.Status = Status;
            return View(user);
        }

        [NonAction]
        public bool IsEmailExist(string emailID)
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.EmailID == emailID).FirstOrDefault();
                return v != null;
            }
        }

        [NonAction]
        public void SendVerificationLinkEmail(string emailID, string activationCode)
        {
            var verifyUrl = "/User/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
            var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);

            var fromEmail = new MailAddress("soalparna@gmail.com", "Jujur Sitanggang");
            var toEmail = new MailAddress(emailID);
            var fromEmailPassword = "sitahuan12345"; // Replace with actual password
            string subject = "Your account is successfully created!";

            string body = "<br/><br/>We are excited to tell you that your wesome account is" +
                " successfully created. Please click on the below link to verify your account" +
                " <br/><br/><a href='" + link + "'>" + link + "</a> ";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            })
            smtp.Send(message);                    
        }
    }
}
```

In model I have one class user.cs this my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RegisstrationAndLogin.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMetadata
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email ID required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 6 characters required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password and password do not match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run my program and I click submit in register I get the following error message:

> The type 'Edm.Binary' of the member 'EmailID' in the conceptual side
>   type 'MyDatabaseModel.User' does not match with the type
>   'System.String' of the member 'EmailID' on the object side type
>   'RegisstrationAndLogin.Models.User'.

Comment: It looks like a mismatch in data types. Make sure that the `EmailID` column in your database is of a `nvarchar(<length>)` type, and not some binary type. Other than that, you have provided way too much unrelated code. A good question focuses on what is important and relevant, and not a dump of lots of code that you happen to have. See [mcve].

Comment: @PeterB  this my database
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (`

    `[UserID]          INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,`

    `[FirstName]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,`
    `[LastName]        VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,`
    `[EmailID]         VARCHAR (254)    NOT NULL,`
   ` [DateOfBirth]     DATETIME         NULL,`
    `[Password]        NVARCHAR(MAX)    NOT NULL,``

i Think is not mismatch in data types

Comment: @PeterB  this my database
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (`

    `[UserID]          INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,`

    `[FirstName]       VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,`
    `[LastName]        VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,`
    `[EmailID]         VARCHAR (254)    NOT NULL,`
   ` [DateOfBirth]     DATETIME         NULL,`
    `[Password]        NVARCHAR(MAX)    NOT NULL,``

i Think is not mismatch in data types
 but when i changes data types to  'nvarchar (<length)' still has not worked

Comment: _"I think is not mismatch in data types"_ - the exception doesn't make up errors. You have updated your column type in the database and perhaps even the generated class, but not your EDMX. Update your EDMX to reflect the database changes, maybe even by manually editing its XML. There also may be an old assembly containing an old EDMX floating around in your bin directory. In short: you changed something, but not all the way through, and aren't mentioning what you did. Read [ask].

Comment: Delete existing edmx and re-generate it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try right clicking on the edmx file and selecting Run Custom Tool

or right click on edmx in solution explorer and open with xml and verify your recent changes
```